# Passing an input value to a window.open method

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want in a form to pass the checked input radio button value to a `window.open` method. Bellow is what I try to use, but always is copied the value of the second input, regardless of what is selected. What is wrong here?

```
onsubmit="window.open(document.getElementByName('option').value);"
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="option" value="http://example1.com" checked> daily
<input type="radio" name="option" value="http://example2.com"> weekly
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use onsubmit=, it can be done with `querySelector` and the [`:checked` pseudoclass](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked). *(Note: Doesn't work in IE8 or earlier, but does in modern browsers back to IE9.)*

```
onsubmit="window.open(document.body.querySelector('input[name=option]:checked').value)"
```

**Live Example:**

```html
<form onsubmit="alert('Would have opened: ' + document.body.querySelector('input[name=option]:checked').value); return false;">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="http://example1.com" checked>daily
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="http://example2.com">weekly
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: OMG, I always thought `:checked` was a jQuery thing, but [nope, it's in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked).

Comment: You don't need the `.body` part, though.

Comment: the .body part should make it quicker - who needs to trawl through the head :D when I say quicker, I mean like a millisecond or something :p

Comment: Oh, it wouldn't be anything like as long as a millisecond. :-)

Comment: Sadly, `:checked` doesn't work on IE8, which still (sadly) has significant market share in the wild. But this is what you want if you don't need IE8 support.

Comment: @t-j-crowder Thank you all for your answers! I am very grateful, but after a deeper analysis of my problem I decided to add an another question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/31502574/1354580.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get the selected (checked) button's value.

If you **don't** need to support IE8 (which sadly [still has significant market share](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0)), [Jaromanda X's answer using `:checked`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31500124/157247) is the way to go.

If you **do** need to support IE8, you'll have to loop through to find out which radio button is checked:

```
function openSelected() {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=option]");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        if (list[i].checked) {
            window.open(list[i].value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your HTML

```
onsubmit="openSelected();"
```

...although I always advocate hooking up event handlers using `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` instead.

**Live Example:**

```js
function openSelected() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=option]");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    if (list[i].checked) {
      alert("Would have opened: " + list[i].value);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="openSelected(); return false;">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="http://example1.com" checked>daily
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="http://example2.com">weekly
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select *which* `option` you want.

[`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns an array. You need to select which element you want.

So you need to use:

```
onsubmit="window.open(document.getElementsByName('option')[0].value);"
```

for the first option, or:

```
onsubmit="window.open(document.getElementsByName('option')[1].value);"
```

for the second option

Answer (score 0):

You could always just asign the input field an ID and call the ID instead of the name. For example:

```
onsubmit="window.open(document.getElementById('IDname').value);"
```

and

```
<input type="radio" id="IDname" name="option" value="http://example1.com" checked> daily
<input type="radio" name="option" value="http://example2.com"> weekly
```